# How to display the same page after login which was clicked before login in php web applications?

Tags: php, mysql

In my application, there are many interests with follow button.I am showing these interests to end user before login.once end user clicks on follow button ,I am redirecting him to login screen.after login, automatically user should follow that interest.

Here my question is ,by using session or cookie is it possible or any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session seems to be the best way. Store interest id in the session and then persist it to the database once successfully logged-in.